# How do you create pagination links related to entries within a Matrix Field in a single entry?

Tags: matrix, relations, pagination, channels, previous-next

I have combed through similar questions, although my pagination links are not performing properly.

I would like to add pagination links to entries within a channel. And I would like for the pagination order to be pulled from an Entries field within a Matrix located within a Single entry.

So far I have:

```
{% set source = craft.entries.sectionId(10).first().gallery.type('gallery').first().entries.relatedTo(entry) %}

{% set prevEntry = entry.getPrev(source) %}
{% set nextEntry = entry.getNext(source) %}

<a href="{{ nextEntry.url }}">Next: {{ nextEntry.title }}</a>
<a href="{{ prevEntry.url }}">Previous: {{ prevEntry.title }}</a>
```

Where SectionId(10.first() is pulling the Single entry and gallery.type('gallery').first().entries is pulling the Entries field within the Matrix.

Unfortunately this is producing blank Next and Previous links.

```
<a href="">Next: </a>
<a href="">Previous: </a>
```

I have referred to other questions regarding params and relations, although through experimenting with different solutions I am not queuing up the correct Next and Previous entries.

Neither is Craft providing any error reports regarding the blank state.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, `.relatedTo(entry)` is not necessary. So long the entry the following code is located within is within the `entry` within the `source` the pagination will populate. Otherwise these will remain empty.

```
{% set source = craft.entries.sectionId(10).first().gallery.type('gallery').first().entries %}

{% set prevEntry = entry.getPrev(source) %}
{% set nextEntry = entry.getNext(source) %}

<a href="{{ nextEntry.url }}">Next: {{ nextEntry.title }}</a>
<a href="{{ prevEntry.url }}">Previous: {{ prevEntry.title }}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your `entry` variable is an entry model within your `source` ElementCriteriaModel?

I'd also recommend to not chain all the methods in a single expression. Getting the models one after the other and storing them into separate vars allows to add some error handling and makes debugging easier.

Comment: The `entry` variable is an entry model within my `source`. Your question helped lead me to my solution. Once I dropped `.relatedTo(entry)` from the source, the pagination worked.